How to Auto select Multi notification & Store the previous alert Trigger condition's price/time Data
I have some doubts :
1:- suppose NSE: NIFTY is at 24300
my entry signal triggered and the system executed ATM CE of 12 Dec on my broker account.
after some time my exit signal was triggered and NSE: NIFTY at that moment @ 24560.
how can It auto-select the entry condition's Strike price during the current market price?
what function should I use for my Indicator to memorize and store the entry condition's price/Time level, so that I can utilize it for Exit order?
2:- Is it possible to auto-select the notification tab for alerts?
suppose I have 3 Trading accounts and I want 3 different setups to execute in all three accounts respectively. but every time I have to create three alerts. I was expecting to create a single alert having multiple conditions and multiple webhook links to execute on different Trading accounts simultaneously.
3:- Is it possible to connect the Algo Trading code setup in Python with the Trading view? I want to execute the Algo setup with the Trading View indicator/strategy.
If I create an Algo Trading code setup using Python, how can I connect it to my Trading View Strategy/Indicator for the execution of orders in the Trading account without any third-party BOT monthly subscription?
Please send/share with me a link where I can learn how to create code for ALGO setup on Python, which can connect to Trading View. So that I can utilize the Webhook link feature via Trading View.
What code do I need to write to connect my Python code (which will replicate an API bridge BOT) with the Trading View alert notification?
I am very new to Pine script. I tried valuewhen but must have some errors. can't rectify.
I don't have Python coding experience, I was curious to create my Trading setup as an Algo Trading setup and utilize the Trading view webhook link feature.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Without coding experience, both in Python and Pine Script, implementing your ideas will be difficult. Stack overflow is not a coding service. For example, for using Tradingview webhooks, various questions with code are available here or at other resources on the internet like Github or Youtube.
